# Removing a newly created element in JavaScript with creating a button

Tags: javascript

I have added a `<p>` to a `<div>` by this code and made a button, too.

```
var selectedId = this.value;
var divElem = $("#selectedItem");

var bElem = document.createElement("Button");
var bElemInnerHTML = document.createTextNode("Erase");
bElem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    remove(this.value);
}, true);
bElem.appendChild(bElemInnerHTML);

var pElem = document.createElement("p");
var pElemInnerHTML = document.createTextNode(this.value);
pElem.setAttribute('id', selectedId);
alert(pElem.getAttribute('id'));
pElem.style.fontSize = '25px';
pElem.style.textAlign = 'center';
pElem.style.margin = '5px';
pElem.appendChild(pElemInnerHTML);
pElem.appendChild(bElem);

divElem.append(pElem);
```

I add to the button to run the `remove` function when clicked on

```
function remove(id){
var emad = document.getElementById(id);
emad.parentNode.removeChild(emad);}'
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does the JS console day? Where do you set the `value` attribute of the button, used in click the event handler?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
bElem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    remove(this.value);
}, true);
```

this.value in the above context refers to the `Button` element's value property(which is a string), not the ID of the Button. Also, you haven't defined the ID, so `this.id` would return `""`(an empty string)

```
bElem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    remove(this.id);
}, true);
```

You can modify `remove()` to accept an Object instead:

```
function remove(btn){
    emad.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
}

bElem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    remove(this);
}, true);
```